# Prove that $ \Vert (\sum_{j \in \mathbb{Z}} |\phi_{2^j} * f|^2)^{1/2}\ \Vert_p \le C\Vert f\Vert_p $

Tags: real-analysis, convolution, harmonic-analysis, schwartz-space

I was trying to prove the following inequality:
Given $\phi$ a Schwartz function in $\mathbb{R}^d$  such that $\int\phi=0$. Let $\phi_t(x)=t^{-d}\phi(xt^{-1})$. 
I need to prove that:
$$ \Vert (\sum_{j \in \mathbb{Z}} |\phi_{2^j} * f|^2)^{1/2}\ \Vert_p \le C\Vert f\Vert_p $$
for all $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$.
 I think that the idea is to prove some weak estimate and conclude by interpolation  theorem, but I do not know how to do it.